# Sling Testing Tools Selector configuration

Tags: sling

AEM 5.6.1

I am trying to run some server side testing using the sling testing tools. I have deployed the `junit.core` bundle and I can navigate to the `JUnitServlet` at /system/sling/junit/

When I hit this url there are tests visible from multiple bundles, I don't want to run the adobe ones but I can't figure out how to filter package names past the period using the url.

e.g

Available tests:

```
com.adobe.stuff
com.my.stuff
```

I tried:

```
/system/sling/junit/com/ <--works but isn't detailed enough
/system/sling/junit/com.my <-- breaks unsurprisingly 
/system/sling/junit/com%2Emy <-- also breaks with 501
```

Is there an expected way of doing this? I couldn't find any documentation about this and the javadoc didn't really help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/system/sling/junit/com.my.html should work - you are right that the /system/sling/junit servlet should make this more explicit. There are examples of running such tests from proxy JUnit tests in the Sling codebase, see [SlingServerSideTest](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/samples/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/sling/testing/samples/integrationtests/serverside/sling/SlingServerSideTest.java) for example.

Comment: The `.html` was the missing piece of the puzzle. I didn't see that while looking at the samples.